# How would i store a FMDatabase to iCloud

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, icloud

Hi there i am trying to save a FMDatabase to iCloud. I can only save NSData or UIDocument what should i do? Is there a way of doing so? If so please let me know any input will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All files saved to the NSDocumentsDirectory are backed up to iCloud by default. FMDB is just a wrapper around the standard SQLite API, so databases created with it will backed up fine. For more information on iCloud backup [read the docs here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/iCloud/iCloud.html).

Comment: My guess is that the OP probably is looking for writing the file to iCloud for syncing, not for backup.

Comment: @JesseRusak Hmm, you might be right, the question is ambiguous. At any rate, the link I gave to the official docs is the best place for OP to start with iCloud syncing!